# iPad app to access Mac files?

Tags: ipad, mac

Is there an iPad app that that can open Mac files over WiFi on the iPad?

I'm looking for something like Dropbox, I really like the feature it has where you can open the files in Dropbox in other apps on the iPad. I need something like that, just for regular files that are not on Dropbox. Something like Air Video but sends the files to the appropriate application instead of just playing videos in the app.

To be clear, I'm not looking for Splashtop or a similar VNC app. I want to use native iPad apps to open these files.

I'm open to a jailbreak solution, too.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me on why Dropbox doesn't suit your needs? Could you elaborate so we can give you a better answer?

Comment: @Gerry dropbox is not big enough, and it's annoying having to move things in and out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering this

> Is there an iPad app that that can open Mac files over WiFi on the
>   iPad?

I bought a app called [Files Connect](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/files-connect/id404324302?mt=8) on my iPad, I use it to access files over the Network to access shared folders on my Mac using my iPad and iPhone. It is universal app for iPhone/iPad.

It works also with Windows PCs, Dropbox and other services.

You can also use it to access your iPad files using the Mac/Pc (opposite way)

I bought for $5, This is looking too much as a ad (I'm not related to this company), so read description for details.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/files-connect/id404324302?mt=8

Comment: In your opinion this is better than GoodReader?

Comment: @Harry I think Files Connect is very good in for storing files with general purposese and sharing files between iOS and Mac/Pc over the network and without iTunes and dropbox. It does not have any editing features, it can just view some kind of files like txt, jpg, mp3 etc. but you can open with any other app.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the iPad app you're looking for is [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8). The hard work will be setting your Mac up to give GoodReader access to the files you want. If you're looking for soemthing that will work while you're on your home network, you'll want to set it up as an AFP server. [This might help](http://thegeekofmac.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-setup-home-afp-server-on-your.html). If you want to be able to access your files from anywhere in the world, you'll probably want to set up an FTP server. This got harder to do in Lion, but [it's still possible](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/29/start-an-ftp-or-sftp-server-in-mac-os-x-lion/).

Answer (score 1):

I use the web app [Beesy.me](http://www.beesy.me) along with the iPad app [Beesy](http://www.beesapps.com/beesy-ipad-to-do/) to transfer my documents from Mac to iPad.

This combination is a professional one for productivity improvements and collaborative works. Since it syncs between devices and you can attach files to your notes, I always use it to transfer files from Mac to iPad. My iPad is used exclusively for work.

Answer (score -1):

Both Vitim.us and Alesh have already pointed out some good apps.
Although, [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/5519283/how-to-access-your-entire-computer-from-an-ipad) wrote an excellent summary about this topic where they list apps according to the media you want to access from your iPad.

Audio and video can be accessed using [AirVideo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-video-watch-your-videos/id306550020?mt=8) or [StreamToMe](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/streamtome/id325327899?mt=8). If you want to access only documents, then [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-large-pdf-viewer/id306277111?mt=8) (like Alesh has said) is the way to go.

I suggest you take a look at the article and I'm sure you'll find your solution there!